# Can we develop a contact form using only javascript libraries without using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, github

I have a hosting server which is not supporting PHP , but supporting JavaScript Libraries.

Recently hosted one of website in there, but this website include **contact form**, how to perform this task using **only JavaScript libraries**

when I surf internet we can see most of example built with `PHP`,`JavaScript` and `Ajax`. Not with pure client side languages

Comment: Does your hosting support any server side languages?

Comment: server is supporting javascript libraries?? hahahahaha. wtf

Comment: You mean it supports node.js?

Comment: @u_mulder No actually, I' trying to host it in [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) , this is supporting JavaScript only

Comment: @JonStirling it will support node.js , if its possible if so ?

Comment: Ah github pages. The answer as far as I can see is no, this is not possible with just github pages. You'd need to use an external service.

Comment: There is a sort of workaround by adding a html "mailto:youremail" object.. It is not quite the same however, because the os handles this..

Comment: You can do this, if you send the result of the form submit to a server that accepts it. Amazon, Google and just about every other company offers services like this.

Comment: Question is not about PHP or JS rather it's about "what can you run on your server **standalone** with direct access to database and filesystem if needed"